# What will this give as output

Tags: oracle

```
declare
  v number;
begin

  select 1 
    into v 
    from dual 
   where 1=2;

exception
  when others then 
    dbms_output.put_line('A');
  when no_data_found   then
    dbms_output.put_line('B');
end;
```

On executing this I am getting an error but i had read it somewhere that in exception WHEN OTHERS, if placed first will always get executed suppressing other type of exceptions . I was asked this question in an interview and I as above . can somebody please confirm

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  You say that you have executed this code and that you got an error.  You don't say what error you got (I'll guess PLS-00370: OTHERS handler must be last among the exception handlers of a block).  You say that you "read somewhere" that the behavior would be different but you don't tell us where you read that.  Plus you haven't told us what version of Oracle you're using (it is possible that this behavior has changed).  Given that, I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Hi justin ,  I was trying to execute it in oracle 11.2g .  I vaguely remember I had seen it saying that OTHERS if placed first would not let other exception types to execute.  That's all I can remember. the behavior can change depending upon oracle version .


Error I am getting

PLS-00370: OTHERS handler must be last among the exception handlers of a block
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Answer (score 1):

You will get the following error in 11.2G:

```
Error at line 1
ORA-06550: line 11, column 3:
PLS-00370: OTHERS handler must be last among the exception handlers of a block
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
```

You should always have OTHER as the last exception handling block

The WHEN OTHERS clause is used to trap all remaining exceptions that have not been handled by your [Named System Exceptions](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exceptions/named_system.php) and Named Programmer-Defined Exceptions.

If you have only the WHEN OTHERS block in your code, then `"PL/SQL procedure successfully completed."` will be the message. Since the OTHER will never be encountered. A when others is almost always a BUG unless it is immediately followed by a RAISE. The point of an exception block is to catch exceptional conditions you are EXPECTING, handle them gracefully and continue. You should only catch the exceptions you are expecting and can do something about. Let the others propagate out so you can detect them (so you see them)

My suggestion would be "IGNORE WHEN OTHERS TOTALLY"

Comment: In that I guess I was asked the wrong question- The question I was asked was this

If a code block throws a NO_DATA_FOUND error and you have placed exception blocks in the folowing manner what will you get?


EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('a');
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('B');

END;

what you will get as output?  I said we will get 'a' .

Comment: If that is the case, you will never get any output since it is an error to have any exception after WHEN OTHERS.

Answer (score 0):

Executing this code block will raise the exception `PLS-00370` (documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/pcmus.htm#sthref18413)):

> **PLS-00370: OTHERS handler must be last among the exception handlers of a block**
>
> **Cause:** One or more exception handlers appear after an OTHERS handler. However, the OTHERS handler must be the last handler in a
>   block or subprogram because it acts as the handler for all exceptions
>   not named specifically.
>
> **Action:** Move the OTHERS handler so that it follows all specific exception handlers.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to leave the OTHERS exception in the last place .
For instance:
BEGIN
  something
EXCEPTION
  THEN WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX
     do something
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   last exception do something
END;

Comment: Please format your answer (code fragments) properly.